# How to share a selective screenshot in a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, screenshot, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share a screenshot of specific area of my screen via the UIActivityViewControler social share features.

I imagine I need to essentially nest the instructions to screenshot and the dimensions of desired screenshot location within the the UIActivityViewControler code but I am not sure how this should look.

I assume it the screenshot instructions need to go here:

```
activityitems = @[_postText.text = @"Here is a selected screenshot.",  _postImage.image = ***screenshot instructions***];
```

How do I properly put in the screenshot instructions and what should they be in this case?